# How to add reference to framework component in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, dependencies, visual-studio-2022

Using Visual Studio 2022, how do I add framework dependencies to a class library?

If I right click on Dependencies, I have options to add Project, Shared Projects, COM and Browse references. There is no option to add Framework dependencies.

Looking at my WinForms project, I see the component I want is *C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\6.0.8*. So I can click the Browse button and navigate to this folder, but the Browse function wants a filename.

If I right click on the Frameworks entry under Dependencies, I get no context menu whatsoever.

I see no way to add this component to the list of dependencies for this class library project.

Comment: Which SDK is the csproj file using? You shouldn't need to do this if you already have `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">` I think.

Comment: @DavidG: It's a class library using .NET 6.0 with `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"`. I don't want it to be a WinForms project. It will have no forms. But I need it to access some WinForms classes.

Comment: You can still change the class library to use that SDK

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, you're right. I can. But doing so doesn't seem to make those symbols available. For example, if I do Ctrl+. on the `Form` symbol, it has no idea what it is.

Comment: Try adding `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` to the csproj file too

Comment: @DavidG: Thanks. That does work. Those symbols are now available.

Comment: You should have just used the Windows Forms Class Library project template in the first place, although that doesn't help if you decided you needed WinForms support after creating the project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to get this done is to modify your csproj file. You need to change the target framework and tell it to use WinForms:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> 

  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework> <!-- Change this -->
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms> <!-- Add this -->
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: FYI, when I brought this all together, I got the warning `warning NETSDK1137: It is no longer necessary to use the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop SDK. Consider changing the Sdk attribute of the root Project element to 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk'.` So I changed that back. Looks like `UseWindowsForms` is all that was needed. Strange to me as I'm used to just including additional references.

Comment: You are correct. I did test it out before posting but I did miss another step, I have included it now.